# JSON.stringify does not give data in proper format

Tags: json, node.js

My code is as shown below:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws'),
    ws = new WebSocket('wss://api.gemini.com/v1/marketdata/BTCUSD');


const getMarketUpdates = (req, res) => {
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        res.json({
            data: JSON.stringify(message.message)
        })
    });
}
```

The output that I am getting is as shown below:

```
{
    "data": "\"{\\\"type\\\":\\\"update\\\",\\\"eventId\\\":1131320868,\\\"timestamp\\\":1501324222,\\\"timestampms\\\":1501324222132,\\\"events\\\":[{\\\"type\\\":\\\"change\\\",\\\"side\\\":\\\"bid\\\",\\\"price\\\":\\\"2702.14\\\",\\\"remaining\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"delta\\\":\\\"-0.12\\\",\\\"reason\\\":\\\"cancel\\\"}]}\""
}
```

Now what should I do to make output look clean?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. On SO, you're not allowed to edit the question such that it invalidates existing answers. But if the second part of your edit (the output quoted at the end) was what you're getting with your original code (it's what I'd expect), it's fine to edit *that* part.

Answer (score 4):

[`JSON.stringify` is not broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). You're double-encoding your data, by using `JSON.stringify` to give `data` a string value, and passing the object containing `data` into `res.json`, which takes that object and encodes it as JSON.

If you want `data` to be the message, just don't use `JSON.stringify` and let `res.json` do it:

```
res.json({
    data: message.message
})
```

Comment: I did as you have mentioned, but it is giving me output `{}`. That's why I have written with res.josn with `message` only. Please see my updated question

Comment: @MrugeshThaker: If `message.message` contains what you've shown, the above definitely will not just output `{}`. (Edit: Just proved it locally, to be extra sure. :-) )